# Can confidential data be gotten from a "hibernation file"?

Tags: physical, confidentiality, physical-access

When a computer `hibernates`, AFAIK a copy of the RAM is saved into a file on disk.

Is this a potential security flaw, knowing someone can take the disk and read the RAM freely?

Comment: Related to [Are encryption keys wiped from RAM before hibernate, or how to do it (Luks and Truecrypt)](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/96883/are-encryption-keys-wiped-from-ram-before-hibernate-or-how-to-do-it-luks-and-t)

Comment: Regarding whether this is a security flaw portion of your question, it's only a flaw if you misrepresent it's secureness.